# Creating an install script

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, installation

I've not messed with installing software probably since early 2000s but I was wondering what the ideal way was now. I used to use InstallShield but I sorta remember VS.NET having their own install service that could be used?

What I need to be able to do is copy/create files and insert paths/values into config files based on where the install installs the files. Can this be done with VS.NET or do I need a 3rd party tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Visual Studio 2010 has setup projects, but they are going away in VS 11 (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2011/03/17/visual-studio-setup-projects-vdproj-will-not-ship-with-future-versions-of-vs.aspx).

[Wix](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) is an option, but the learning curve is rather steep.

InstallShield is also still an option.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend innosetup
http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php

It uses a reasonably easy to learn proprietary script and for me works every time

I've no idea if MS have their own means in VS.NET